# Extracting XML from a sharepoint page

Tags: xml, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint page and I've been asked to build some XSL to display it "nicer" in a data view web part, but whenever I view the code it seems that XSL has already been applied.  I'd like to extract the raw XML so I take it out of Sharepoint Designer and test it against some custom XSL in Visual Studio.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst4690_How-to-see-the-raw-XML-content-document.aspx). You want to try and dump the XML out so that you can customise the XSLT.

You can change the data view web part's XSL via it's properties (if I recall!). Paste this XSL into the web part's XSL template:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage"/>
```

Hopefully this should dump out the XML data that the XSL is using.

EDIT:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384713/how-to-display-xml-returned-by-sharepoint-for-web-parts) SO question might help also.